# How can I save video played in VideoView using Http streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming

How can I save video played in VideoView using Http streaming so that if user play it again it can be played without downloading it again from streaming server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no access to the stream data being pulled in by `VideoView` (or the underlying `MediaPlayer`).

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way currently to save/cache streamed file locally ?

Comment: @NarendraJain: Correct. After all, you are not the one doing the download.

Comment: I know the post is old, but just in case. There is [this](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) library that does it. didn't check it tough